# Partial answer accepted, thinking it could have been easily extended and provided enough insights

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer, exact-duplicates, questions

Some days ago I posted a question and I accepted an answer, "although it’s only a very partial answer," as the answer author wrote in a comment. I accepted it because I thought that it sufficiently provided insights to see that my conjecture was false (even if an assumption was added restricting the validity of my conjecture). However, I now think that the conjecture is true in general, and therefore I would like to find other answers to help me prove it.

What should I do? I don't want to remove my acceptance flag because I already accepted since it is indeed insightful (and the answer author already thanked me a lot).

Comment: You could post another question, linking to the older one, carefully explaining why you're posting the new one.

Comment: Thank you, @GerryMyerson, for your suggestion!